# How can I use external HTML form in Joomla site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, joomla

I have created a HTML form designed with external CSS, images and JS file, now I need to add this HTML page into existing Joomla as Item page. How do I do that? It should show me the same header and footer of Joomla layout only the content should be my HTML form which contains scripts for ajax request and front-end validation, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Provide us some code example.

Comment: I think i have clearly mentioned the issue on my question already, I have a html page with external css and images want to add that file into joomla as article, I have already tried **custom html** extension but didn't work, page breaks.

Comment: Did you try using an iFrame?

Comment: No, i will try with iframe tomorrow, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So, the form should have his own `head` and `body` tags ?

Comment: Turn off filtering, use editor=none and paste the html into an article.

Comment: @Elin I tried using editor=none, but no changes, HTML source is display in view page HTML tags

Comment: @Michel No, the form will start with div and some script tags, Header and Footer will be global layout designs

Comment: iFrame with html form url in root directory, works for me, Thanks @Joost

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Comment: You could use [Sourcerer plugin](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) in order to _include_ this file in an article, as a PHP `include`. The integration would be full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is very late to answer this question.
Even i face the same scenario and fixed it by adding iframe into the page.

```
<iframe src="form/html/url" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```